# some issue with npm run dev

Tags: php, laravel, npm

i have some issue with npm
the npm version is 6.14.8
the laravel version is 8

when i use the `npm run dev` i face this errors :

```
98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                            9:16:24 PM

This dependency was not found:

* -!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-2!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss0!./custom in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css

To install it, you can run: npm install --save -!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-2!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss0!./custom
     Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  598 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './custom' in 'F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\resources\css'
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:925:10
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2830:7
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:6877:13
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:213:14
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:27:15
    at F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
 @ ./resources/css/app.css

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './custom' in 'F:\App\xampp\htdocs\basic\basic-website\resources\css'
 @ ./resources/css/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./resources/css/app.css) 3:10-137
 @ ./resources/css/app.css
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-21T17_46_24_559Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-21T17_46_24_640Z-debug.log
```

i googled the problem but i don't find a solution

if i downgrade to laravel 7 will problem solve ?

anybody could help me please ?

Comment: The message literally tells you how you can fix it. Did you try what it said on the `To install it, you can run` line? Note that this is an `npm` issue, nothing to do with php and very little to do with Laravel.

Comment: Actually, looking at it, it says that it's an issue in `./resources/css/app.css`, so there's probably some bad css in there, pointing to just `./custom`

Comment: yes try the npm install --save but that wasn't the answer

Comment: tnx that soved to me